# Constant knocking noise, rear drivers side

Tags: honda, brakes, noise, civic

Long time user, first time poster!

I know "knocking noises" are prevalent in many questions but I've not quite found the answer to this one...

Bit of history, it's 2002 Civic Type R. Over this weird summer, it's basically sat on the driveway for 5 months...with the occasional start up and half mile round trip. It's quite clear that the brakes have suffered, there's visible rust and they grind when moving (and get hot when driving for a bit). Today, however, when I've gone for a little run, it's now developed a constant knocking noise from the rear drivers side, that increases in speed as you do and vice versa. It's not just when I accelerate, it's also when coasting. It's NOT quiet, it's easily heard. Obviously, I didn't take it particularly far, as I felt like the wheel could pop off at any moment...

I'm convinced that the brake issue, born from a lack of use, is part of the problem, but I've not come across this before. There doesn't appear to be a leak anywhere, from the lack of evidence on the driveway.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some photos of the brakes would be helpful. Also, please check if the wheel nuts/bolts are tight

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned about rust.  That's normal for a sitting brake as the discs are steel.  Did you set the parking brake?  That could be making the noise if the cable seized.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll check the wheel nuts but I don't know why they would be loose to be honest. I tend to leave the handbrake off to stop it seizing up... Should I not do that?

Comment: Knocking? Not much there to cause a knock. Wheel bearing possibly but doubtful.  Tire flat spot from sitting would be more like a thump. Rust buildup on the rotor would be a scraping sound. Sticking caliper maybe? You said it got hot, how hot?  Oh, and loose lug nuts.  How about a video?

Comment: It certainly doesn't feel like a flat spotted tyre... It's definitely a mechanical noise. Bit tricky to video it to be honest. The heat is substantial, too hot to touch after about 10 minutes... If it was a loose caliper, I just would expect the noise to be slightly erratic, but it isn't. It's "rhythm" is exactly 1 revolution of each wheel turn.

Comment: If the wheel gets hot after driving, I'd say definitely a sticky caliper. I would take it off and clean everything up.  Make sure the slide pins are clean and then coat them with brake grease. I always coat the flat areas on the calipers where the pads slide as well.